# Update the first 10000 rows, then the next 10000 and so on?

Tags: oracle, oracle12c

My table has close to 8 million rows. Is there a way to update first 10000 records and then the next 10000 records and so on.. till the 8 millionth record separately in Oracle?

I did check [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9631371/select-the-first-150-rows-then-the-next-150-and-so-on) for *Select* statement. But didn't find any solutions for an *Update* statement. Can someone please help? Hope this would help someone in need in the future.

**UPDATE**: Database version : 12C

Comment: Thanks Mike.  Do the rows need to be updated sequentially (in some predetermined order), or can multiple groups of 10000 be updated in parallel?  Thanks

Comment: Batch update is one solution, have a look at [this](http://www.orafaq.com/node/2450)

Comment: What exactly are you trying to achieve? Do you have any performance issues?

Comment: In a sequential order @alexgibbs.

Comment: Hi Jacob, I had the same thought of a batch. But achieving this through SQL would be my first preference.

Comment: Yes @PavelSmirnov. There is a need of performance monitoring. On the other end, my client's Oracle system is designed in a way that large data update on a single stretch will lead to a user lock. So trying to achieve this.

Comment: @Mike What is the database version?

Comment: Please find my update @Jåcob

Comment: @Mike Why not `MERGE`? Leverage the limit option or other optimization techniques in the `SELECT` statement? Perhaps [this](http://www.dba-oracle.com/t_append_upsert_merge_sql.htm) would be of some help

Comment: @Mike, you can try to use DBMS_SQL_MONITOR package for that task. Refer to https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/TGSQL/tgsql_monit.htm#TGSQL94586

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a simple solution if you know which records has already been updated. At least it will keep your transactions within a reasonable size.

```
DECLARE
    i number := 1;
BEGIN
    while i > 0 loop
      UPDATE < your table >
         SET col = <value>
         WHERE rownum < 100000
           AND <some statement that exclude already updated records>
      i := sql%rowcount;
      commit;
    end loop;
END;
```