# How to load exact number of rows to jTable from MySQL and paginate the remaining?

Tags: java, mysql, swing, pagination

I am trying to load data from MySQL into my Application, where I have a jTable. I want to load only 100 rows using a query, and I can do that successfully as of now. furthermore, I want to paginate that data, in such a way that if I have the next button, and I click on that, the table should be updated with 100 more records and so on.

This method loads the data into the table:

```java
public void showTable(){
        try{ 

            how.res = how.stat.executeQuery("select * from students order by name ASC limit 100");

            while(how.res.next()){
                String id = how.res.getString(1);
                String name = how.res.getString(2);
                String contact = how.res.getString(3);

                Object[] content = {id,name,contact};
                DefaultTableModel model = (DefaultTableModel)jTable1.getModel();
                model.addRow(content);

            }
        }catch (Exception e){

        }
    }
```

I call this method on form Initialization, and now I only get 100 rows into the table, what should I write for the next button to load next 100 rows and update the table?

What I tried:

```java
private void jButton3ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
        // TODO add your handling code here:
        try{ 
            numClick+=100;
            how.res = how.stat.executeQuery("select * from students offset"+numClick+"");

            while(how.res.next()){
                String id = how.res.getString(1);
                String name = how.res.getString(2);
                String contact = how.res.getString(3);

                Object[] content = {id,name,contact};
                DefaultTableModel model = (DefaultTableModel)jTable1.getModel();
                model.addRow(content); 
            }
        }catch (Exception e){

        }  
    }
```

But this does not give me any result.

Here is the Connection:

```
public class JoinConnection {

    public Connection con;
    public Statement stat;
    public ResultSet res;

    public JoinConnection(){

        systemConnection();
    }

    public void systemConnection(){
        try{
        Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
        con =(com.mysql.jdbc.Connection) DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/library","root","");
                stat = (Statement) con.createStatement();
        }catch(ClassNotFoundException | SQLException e){System.out.println(e);}
    }
}
```

I am using NetBeans with MySQL. if the question is not clear, please tell me for clarification.

**EDIT:** Thanks to @George Z. We solved the problem by changing the button method into something like below. I am editing the question because I can not write the answer in comments:

```
private void jButton3ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         

    try{ 
        numClick+=100;
        DefaultTableModel model = (DefaultTableModel)jTable1.getModel();
        model.setRowCount(0);
        how.res = how.stat.executeQuery("select * from students limit "+numClick+" , 100");

            while(how.res.next())
            {
            String id = how.res.getString(1);
            String name = how.res.getString(2);
            String contact = how.res.getString(3);

            Object[] content = {id,name,contact};
            model.addRow(content);
            }
        }catch (SQLException e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }  
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An opinion-tip: Do not swallow exceptions, and do not face any specific type of exception as `Exception`. In your case, you should be catching them as `SQLException` and at least print their stacktrace.

Since your first page - query is `"select * from students order by name ASC limit 100"` the next page - next query should be something like `"select * from students order by name ASC limit "+numClick+" , 100"` with numClick increased by 100 in every page. Of course `numClick` variable should be handled by a `PreparedStatement`. Read here [how to use prepared statements](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/prepared.html).

In order to understand `LIMIT` take a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9631371/select-the-first-150-rows-then-the-next-150-and-so-on) answered question in addition.

Another way that you could give a chance, if your data is kind of small, is to load everything in memory (a data structure), and then populate the data from there.

When you change page, you will have to current data from the table. A simple search will guide you in this [question.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6232355/deleting-all-the-rows-in-a-jtable)

Comment: That is OK, works now! but it does not update the table, the next 100 is continuously added. I want the next 100 to overwrite the previous ones in the table.

Comment: should I use my second query in preparedStatement then?

Comment: @Hefaz Yes, but i did not give much attention to it, because this is a different story.

Comment: Thank you so much. The problem is solved now. I did it without a prepared Statement. I will edit the method for the button in the question.

Answer (score 0):

You could use `LIMIT 0, 100`

```
SELECT * FROM students ORDER by name ASC LIMIT 0, 100    // Returns 1   -> 100
SELECT * FROM students ORDER by name ASC LIMIT 100, 101  // Returns 101 -> 201
SELECT * FROM students ORDER by name ASC LIMIT 200, 101  // Returns 201 -> 301
```